# How to dynamically set date from Core data in a textfield in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to try to update a diary and when I click on the datePicker and changes date, the textfield date does not update instantly. It updates when I click on update button and go to the home view and come back. Please help if could.

This is the Home View of my app.

[image]

The is when I click on the any record(update view)

[image]

This is what I've tried.
`@State var diary: MyDiary_Entity`. diary is my object of the entity.

[image]

Comment: Check out [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3585796) and replace the image with [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code

Comment: What's wrong with the code you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

If you use @ObservedObject var diary: Diary then body will be called when it changes.

By the way your date formatting and binding supplied to DatePicker have mistakes. And I think you are doing too much in that View struct.